# Is Sales force WSDL specific to user or can be use for user

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am creating an application to export data in sales force where user enter their username password and security token. So on WSDL will work for all or every user have specific WSDL?

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The enterprise WSDL is different between each different organization, and generally you can use organziation 1's WSDL with organization 2's users. the Partner WSDL however is the same for everyone, and is designed for cases like this where you want to write one tool that many different organizations and users can use.

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL will work for all of them, but you have to make a login call (from the partner WSDL for example) using the User's Username, Password & Security token to get a session ID. You then use that session ID for any subsequent calls to get data etc..